# mocking a function in jest to test in typescript

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-testing-library

```
// file to be mocked.ts
export function Details(): void {name=x;email=y}
```

I want to mock this function in my test file so that I can change the name and email in mocked function in typescript

Comment: Hi Sarfraj, welcome to StackOverflow. jest provides [3 ways](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#the-4-ways-to-create-an-es6-class-mock)(not sure why they say about 4 ways) to mock some module. what have you tried so far and why it did not work to you?

Comment: can you share a simple mock of this function how to do it i have tried few things but none is working at last i added this                                                                `jest.mock("mocked.ts");
Details as jest.MockedFunction<VoidFunction>`

Comment: and then `name=newname;  email=newemail`;

Comment: i want to do this changes inside that function which is giving some typescript error

Comment: Where did you declare `name`, `email`, `x`, and `y` variables? Please provide the completed code and clarify your question.